# How to update doc after foreach in firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I would like to update every document what I get.
So first I get all relevant document, every get new push notification, but I would like to set data on every document.

Here is code:

```
const pushok = await db.collection('Users')
  .where('aktiv', '==', 1)
  .where('uzemmod', '==', 1).get();


if (pushok.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
} else {
  pushok.forEach(doc => {

    //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SET doc.data().lastpush: time;

    let payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Üzeneted érkezett!',
        body: 'Üzenet',
        sound: 'default',
      },
      data: {
        "messageid": "1"
      }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(doc.data().notificationtoken, payload);

    console.log('Üzenet elküldve', doc.data().notificationtoken);

  });

}
```

I don't know how to update within foreach. Batched writes work, but I think maybe I need more than 500, so need transaction? Or what is the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to execute a variable number of asynchronous Firebase method calls in parallel (and you may have more that 500 Firestore document updates), you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), as follows:

Note that we build an array that contains the Promises returned by the Firestore updates **and** the Notification sendings and we pass it to `Promise.all()`.

```
    const pushok = await db.collection('Users')
        .where('aktiv', '==', 1)
        .where('uzemmod', '==', 1).get();


    if (pushok.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
    }
    else {
        const promises = [];
        pushok.forEach(doc => {

            // Pushing the asynchronous doc update
            promises.push(doc.ref.update({ lastpush: time }))  // I don't know where you define time...

            let payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'Üzeneted érkezett!',
                    body: 'Üzenet',
                    sound: 'default',
                },
                data: {
                    "messageid": "1"
                }
            };

            // Pushing the asynchronous notification sending               
            promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(doc.data().notificationtoken, payload));

            console.log('Üzenet elküldve', doc.data().notificationtoken);

        });

        await Promise.all(promises)

    }
```

Comment: "// I don't know where you define time..." I defined time before this. :) Thanks, its work! :)